# Stop ListView scroll animation

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with about 100 entries. When the user does the "fling" from bottom to top it starts scrolling and keeps on scrolling even when the finger does not touch the display any more.

Is there a way to stop the scrolling animation at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there surely is a way to do it. But the point is more whether or not it is advisable to do it, in my opinion.

The list is a standard Android control that behaves constistently across all applications. So I would be surprised if I found a list that did not behave the same in your application. You can stop the fling by putting your finger back on the screen at any time.

That said, if you want to do extra work, you could subclass the list view and override its on touch method. Best way to know what to do is to get the source code of ListView ([ListView in Android 1.6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/ListView.java)).

Comment: I would echo MarvinLabs' comment about keeping your list consistent with how the user *expects* it to work.

Answer (score 16):

and we lookup the android source code (AbsListView), give it a ACTION_CANCEL touchEvent, can stop the fling. it is easy.

```
listView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: This is the right answer. This should be accepted as it works without reflection. Nice work mate!

Answer (score 9):

I didn't try the solution of [`Pompe de velo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369491/stop-listview-scroll-animation/6369860#6369860) but since [`smoothScrollToPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) is not available for API level less than 8 this didnt work for me.

I agree, changing default behaviour is **not** a good Idea, but sometimes you need to. So here is my (dirty) solution which uses reflection. This is by far not the recommended way since it's a hack but it works for me. There might be a better solution but I didn't found it.

```
class StopListFling {

    private static Field mFlingEndField = null;
    private static Method mFlingEndMethod = null;

    static {
        try {
            mFlingEndField = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFlingRunnable");
            mFlingEndField.setAccessible(true);
            mFlingEndMethod = mFlingEndField.getType().getDeclaredMethod("endFling");
            mFlingEndMethod.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mFlingEndMethod = null;
        }
    }

    public static void stop(ListView list) {
        if (mFlingEndMethod != null) {
            try {
                mFlingEndMethod.invoke(mFlingEndField.get(list));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful to me. Native Android widgets do this too (this is only a guess..): If you put a listview inside a viewpager and fling the list, then swipe left, the pager will stop the scrolling manually.

Comment: @arul That is the full code, just use this method on your list view instance to stop the scroll. There's not much to explain. It uses reflection to hack internal fields of ListView. Anyways, I would recommend to take a look at smoothScrollToPosition first if you're targeting API >= 8.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent flinging for ListViews in API 8 by overriding onTouchEvent and calling smoothScrollBy.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        this.smoothScrollBy(0, 0);
        break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

This takes over from the fling scrolling and scrolls 0px instead.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you shouldn't modify this behaviour, since the fling behaviour is what the user expects.

However, to your question. I haven't tried this but in theory it should work.

Implement an [`OnScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to your `ListView` and use the [`onScrollStateChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScrollStateChanged%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int%29) method to check if the current state is [`SCROLL_STATE_FLING`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#SCROLL_STATE_FLING). After you've determined that the scrolling perfoms by a fling you can get your `ListView`'s first visible position by using the [`getFirstVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) method and from there you can use [`smoothScrollToPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) where you put in your `getFirstVisiblePosition()` value as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

if you what disable default animation from list view just need set **id**  for root (main) layout in xml and call void  **onClickListener** in class for root layout