# MPAndroidChart: How to cancel fling event?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

With MPAndroidChart, how can I stop an ongoing fling event initiated by the user?

Example: 
User flings the plot backwards, plot keeps scrolling backwards after touching. User presses button "Resume", app calls `chart.moveViewToX(dataSet.getEntryCount())`, but view is not actually moved until the fling event comes to a complete halt, which can take several seconds.

In other words, I am looking for a solution that executes `moveViewToX` immediately without waiting for the fling to complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By dispatching a new `ACTION_DOWN` event, we can stop the ongoing fling event:

```
chart.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
```

Source:
[Stop ListView scroll animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369491/stop-listview-scroll-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Faking a MotionEvent into the system is not the best solution, especially there is no matching MotionEvent.ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL.

For the MPAndroidChart one can use the

`((BarLineChartTouchListener)touchListener).stopDeceleration();`

to stop the fling action. Whether this method is implemented depends on your chart type. The above example assume you are having a line chart.